# Use Native Java UUID.getRandom() as Sharding key and as the _id?

Tags: mongodb, random, uuid, sharding, mongodb-java

I understand that with a write-heavy application, using the ObjectId is a really bad idea for a sharding key. **However, would it be a good idea to use native *UUID.randomUUID() from Java** as a Shard key since they are truly random and won't cause hotspotting for a single shard.

These IDs are **128 bit ID** and look like :

- 5842fa92557947f1b020041ff74868a4
- 308947443e564d80b97dd8411b4b727e
- f8a7ee765bed4ce3bcc5800ac3a2a710
- 1bcfd08b89e94c58ae7695b3e7a1bc4f

It's very similar to an ObjectId (96bit int).

Plus, since this is mandatory to have an Index on the _id, the shard key would be the _id and we would save RAM by creating another index for the shard_key. Everything collection would be ready for sharding.

Is it for performances issues within **Mongod** or for disk/ram space problem?

The collision rate for a UUID is ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)) : 
*only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%. The probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using UUID would distribute your write access across the shards but you would have no query isolation, so you'll have less than optimum results with your queries. The fastest queries are the one answered by only one shard.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-internals/#sharding-shard-key-query-isolation

That would help to know what is in your collection to help you more efficiently.

Comment: So I would be better to shard, for say, my Accounts using their _id and every other table linked to my Accounts (like Furniture, Rights, Orders) based on a new Index using the AccountId? Would it be better to shard on AccountId + Furniture._id or only on AccountId, assuming I will always provide the AccountId.

Answer (score 1):

Using UUIDs is perfectly ok (provided that you are only going to lookup those documents by their primary/shard key). One of the purposes of shard key is to group related documents together. If we're building, say, flickr, our shard key would start with `user_id`, so that photos of a user sit together on one shard. If your documents are not related and primary key is also a shard key, then there's no problem.

Comment: And anyone knows why 10gen didn't go that way from the beginning to avoid a lot of headache for developers, assuming this is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

You may run into a problem due to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-403, which is slated to be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks to point this out. Also, I don't know if the benchmark is still up to date but using UUID vs ObjectId seems very problematic for MongoDB.